# Kafka server change log level

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, log4j

I am trying to change the logging level in Kafka server, because the logs are too verbose. I have looked at which classes log at the DEBUG level and got log line counts e.g.:

```
kafka.cluster.Partition 1235094
o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient    70375
o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler   69363
kafka.log.LogCleanerManager$    56400
```

For instance, a log line from the `kafka.cluster.Partition` class logger looks like this:

```
21:41:01.041 [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-4] DEBUG kafka.cluster.Partition - [Partition __transaction_state-43 broker=3] Recorded replica 1 log end offset (LEO) position 0 and log start offset 0.
```

I tried to configure the `log4j.properties` by adding the following lines:

```
log4j.logger.kafka.cluster.Partition=INFO
log4j.additivity.kafka.cluster.Partition=false
```

I was expecting to find that `kafka.cluster.Partition` only logs at INFO level. Instead, I find that it still logs at DEBUG level.

How can I fix this?

Using Kafka 3.0.0

Sharing the full log4.properties below, as requested in comments. I believe this is quite close to the default version that ships with the Kafka server.

Note that our corporate framework for running any server redirects both stdout and stderr to a single application log file, so it probably does not matter which appender we specify. What I am looking to do is filter which lines get logged, which should not depend on which appender is used.

```
kafka.logs.dir=logs

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.cleanerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/log-cleaner.log
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/controller.log
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

# Turn on all our debugging info
#log4j.logger.kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=DEBUG, kafkaAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.client.ClientUtils=DEBUG, kafkaAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.perf=DEBUG, kafkaAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.perf.ProducerPerformance$ProducerThread=DEBUG, kafkaAppender
#log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient=DEBUG
log4j.logger.kafka=INFO, kafkaAppender

log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false

#log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.additivity.kafka.server.KafkaApis=false
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=false

log4j.logger.kafka.controller=INFO, controllerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.controller=false

log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=INFO, cleanerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.log.LogCleaner=false

log4j.logger.state.change.logger=INFO, stateChangeAppender
log4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false
```

Comment: Which file are you referring to? `cleanerAppender` writes to different file than the main server logs

Comment: Can you share your log4j.properties file?

Comment: @OneCricketeer We redirect both stdout and stderr of the Kafka server process to a single application log file. (Corporate framework, not my choice.) Still, regardless of WHERE the output goes, I was expecting that my specifications would filter WHAT is being logged. I can change the appender name for this entry, but I don't expect that to change anything.

Comment: The line you've added only applies for the `cleanerAppender`, though

Comment: @OneCricketeer I imagine that log4j, when called from class C, figures out (1) is this message above the log level for class C? (2) if so, find the appender(s) and write to them. I'll change the appender to be stdout, but I don't expect that to matter.

Comment: Look at `log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient=DEBUG` line. This applies to all appenders

Comment: @OneCricketeer As you suggested, I removed the appender specification from the class I am trying to filter. Restarted server. Same logging behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at which JARs are in the classpath, I concluded that our installation of Kafka (plus some custom code which probably brought in dependencies) was actually logging through `logback`. Found these JARs in the classpath:

```
logback-classic-1.0.11.jar
logback-core-1.0.11.jar
```

So I dropped a `logback.xml` in the classpath instead of modifying the `log4j.properties` that was probably being ignored.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The result is that logging has been reduced to the level specified in the `logback.xml`.